# mPDF footer page number to other language

Tags: php, mpdf

I want mPDF page number in Bengali. I use the function below to covert English number.

```
function en2bn($num)
{
    $num_bn = array('০','১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯');
    $num_eng = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
    $nums = str_replace($num_eng, $num_bn, $num);
    return $nums;    
}
```

I am using mpdf [Replaceable Aliases](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/replaceable-aliases.html) to generate page number:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('{PAGENO}/{nbpg}');
```

I can not find any way to pass Replaceable Aliases through function.